# How to set up Django model inheritance with foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have three models, one superclass and two subclasses. Both subclasses belong to another model (expressed through a foreign key).

I am not really sure what the best setup would look like in regards to my FK? Do I put the foreign key in the superclass, in the subclass, or in both? Maybe there is also not only one way, but multiple ways of doing it?

Every building can have many energy objects, which means it can have many Heating and Cooling objects. Every Heating/Cooling/Energy object belongs to one building. So a classic One-to-many relationship expressed with a Foreign Key.

Here are my models:

Superclass

```
class Energy(models.Model):
   year : models.BigIntegerField(...)
   value : models.IntegerField(...)
   connected_building : ForeignKey ??????
```

Subclasses

```
class Heating(Energy): 
   connected_building : ForeignKey ?????


class Cooling(Energy): 
   connected_building : ForeignKey ?????
```

Related class

```
class Building(models.Model):
  name = models.Charfield(...)
```

I am kind of scared of messing up my db, so any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it should be in superclass

Comment: Thanks ruddra for your comment. So if I put it into the superclass it would be inherited by the subclasses and every time I create a new heating/cooling object it would be dynamically related to Buildings. And same for a new energy object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `Energy` an abstract superclass where you won't have to deal with a separate Energy table in database. You can keep the ForeignKey to the building in `Energy` model as you described. More info for abstract models can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).

Comment: thank you cagrias. Yes, I guess this is what I need. Just to be sure: Since it won't create a db-table, I can't create instances of energy, correct? And giving the Superclass energy a foreign key, will ensure (through inheritance) that my subclasses have a foreign_key field that relates them to buildings, right?

Comment: You won't have Energy table but all of your models inherited from Energy table will have ForeignKey fields.

Comment: I will go with this. But just for learning purposes. What would be the way to go if I needed to create also instances of energy class? Putting the FK into the Superclass or subclasses?

Comment: You just need to delete the ```abstract = True``` only :) Remaining will be the same.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!